# Can I make double clicking a word to highlight it ignore trailing commas?

Tags: high-sierra, text

For example in Adobe Reader I'd like to double click a word to highlight it, but not have it include the trailing comma if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be how Adobe Acrobat / Adobe Reader handles PDF text selection. Apple's Preview app handles double click text selection as you would want. If using Adobe Reader isn't critical to your workflow for this document, I would consider using Preview for it.

Comment: Compulsory [xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/927/) ;-)